# How to test if all sub classes have been tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing, class, tdd, subclass

So I am really bad about not remembering to make unit tests for new classes that I've created. I try my best to adhere to TDD, but sometimes I forget. I'm good about running tests (as it is just one button) So is there a way to scan a namespace for all classes, and check to see if they are derived from a known class.

For instance. I have a Contact class. I have 3 sub classes of Contact (Shipping, Billing, Service) I have a unit test for all 3. Lets say a month from now I decide to derive another class from Contact. I'm super good about remember to run my unit tests, but in this case I would want it to fail just 1 test to remind me to write a unit test for my new contact class. Something like.

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Contact")]
    public void TestAllContactsAccountedFor()
    {
        foreach(class c in theNamespace)
        {
            bool subclassOfContact = c is  Contact;
            if (subclassOfContact)
            {
                bool knownSubclass = (c is CustomerShippingContact) || (c is CustomerBillingContact) || (c is CustomerServiceContact);
                Assert.IsTrue(knownSubclass);

            }

        }
    }
```

this way if I forget to make a test it will fail this test, and then I account for it. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Mighty Moose a.k.a. ContinuousTests](http://www.continuoustests.com/) it actually warns you about untested code and is the only code coverage tool for .NET that is free.

Comment: Given nCrunch has just gone commercial, I recently looked at ContinousTests, but I couldn't see how it provided this same functionality. Can you point us at any online resource demonstrating this @bitbonk?

Comment: The videos on their site are pretty detaile, IMHO.

Comment: I just installed Mighty Moose... Free is nice :) I'm a little surprised that VS 2010 pro doesn't have something for this already.

Comment: @AlSki The main feature that is different/missing in Mighty Mose compared to NCrunch in code coverage, but that wasn't added on purpose: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2012/03/21/code-coverage-2/

Comment: @bitbonk: +1, but how do we know it won't go commercial also? :)

Comment: so far the only things I don't like about (and they is very minor) is that it can't test when I cover a private method through reflection. And it only shows the numbers on left sometimes on my classes. But otherwise I like it. It wasn't as cpu hungry as NCrunch was, and it was very easy to install.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than solving this with Code, may I suggest you investigate the use of coverage of your tests. 
In particular have a look at nCrunch which will mark lines of your codebase that are already being used in tests, so you can easily identify which need mroe tests writing. See http://ncrunch.net

Comment: I agree, for example DotCover (http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) works in the same way - marks tested and untested lines of code, calculates % of coverage and so on.

Comment: thank you for that. I had just found a "solution" using linq and reflection, but it appears you have to have unit tests in the same project, and my unit tests are in a different project with a different namespace. I have to wait 8 minutes to accept you answer, but i will then. Thank you.